# Transcendence degree of the fraction field of $k[G]$ for torsion-free abelian group $G$

Tags: commutative-algebra, field-theory, abelian-groups, group-rings, transcendence-degree

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $p$ and $G$ be a torsion-free abelian group. Then the group ring $k[G]$ is an integral domain , let $k(G)$ denote its field of fractions . Then can we say anything about the transcendence degree of $k(G)$ over $F_p$  in terms of $k$ and/or $G$ ? What about the transcendence degree of $k(G)$ for field $k$ of characteristic $0$ ?

Comment: I would believe that the transcendence degree is precisely the rank of the group $G$.

Comment: For completeness: this question was crossposted, saying that it was, [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/283695/transcendence-degree-of-the-fraction-field-of-kg-for-torsion-free-abelian-gr).

Answer (score 2):

Let $A\subset G$ be the subgroup generated by a maximal $\mathbf{Z}$-free family (so $A$ is free and $G/A$ is torsion). Then $k(A)=k(G)$. In addition, $A\simeq\mathbf{Z}^{(I)}$, where $I\subset A$ is a basis, and then we see that $k(A)$ is the field of rational fractions in the indeterminates $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ and $k(A)\subset k(G)$ is an algebraic extension. So their common transcendency degree over $k$ is the cardinal $|I|$, that is, equal to the $\mathbf{Q}$-rank $d=\dim_{\mathbf{Q}}(A\otimes_{\mathbf{Z}}\mathbf{Q})$ of $A$.

If $t$ is the transcendency degree of $k$ over $\mathbf{F}_p$, then it follows that the transcendency degree of $k(G)$ over $\mathbf{F}_p$ is $t+d$.

Comment: why is $k(A)=k(G)$ ?

Comment: Sorry! Now corrected: it's just an algebraic extension (a finite algebraic extension when $G/A$ is finite), which is enough.

Comment: You have still written $k(A)=k(G)$ though ... can you please explain why is it an algebraic extension ?

Comment: It boils down to finite index inclusions. Then by standard theorems on abelian groups it boils down to the inclusion $\mathbf{Z}^d\oplus p\mathbf{Z}\subset \mathbf{Z}^{d+1}$, which corresponds to $k(x_1,\dots,x_d,x_{d+1}^p)\subset k(x_1,\dots,x_{d+1})$, which is clearly a finite extension.

Comment: Actually I can't require $A$ to be maximal free abelian, which usually does not exist (e.g., in $\mathbf{Q}$), and indeed $A\neq G$ implies $k(A)\neq k(G)$.

Comment: Now what do you mean by maximal $\mathbb Z$-free family ?

Comment: A subset $I$ of an abelian group $A$ is $\mathbf{Z}$-free if the canonical homomorphism $\mathbf{Z}^{(I)}\to A$ (mapping identically $I$ to itself) is injective. Here $\mathbf{Z}^{(I)}$ is the free abelian group on $I$, the group of finitely supported functions $I\to\mathbf{Z}$. Informally, this is just a maximal subset with no nontrivial linear relation. For instance, in $\mathbf{Q}$, any nonzero singleton is such a family.